# How to create a torus with divided cuts that correspond to the direction of the torus

Tags: mesh, geometry

I have a question about the mesh and geometry of a torus and how to achieve a certain physical effect.

[image]

This is what I am talking about. I need to have a divided cut that is perpendicular to the direction of the faces of the torus.

Here is a picture of what I want to acheive:
[image]

Notice how the torus-es/curves each have dividing segments that lie inbetween the faces of the torus?
I'd like to achieve this effect, but I am not sure how to. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create the basic shape you want for your rings.

[image]

Add an array modifier to it.

[image]

Add a curve>Circle to the scene.

On you object add a curve modifier after the array and select the circle as object.

[image]

Depending select the correct axis for the curve modifier so that your array becomes an indented tours-like object.
Then adjust the settings for the array and the sizing of the object and the circle to your needs.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I see that you are using a texture to achieve the effect. My suggestion is to you make a texture but with vertical straight lines and in the Mapping panel in blender choose Cordinates: Generated and Projection: Tube. In the 3D viewport it's gonna look weird but in the render it's fine.

If you need more rings just increase the repeat value in Image Mapping.

[image: :D]

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this in Cycles,please?

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to accomplish this is something like the follow:

1. while in edit mode, select all edges that have that direction under
2. select menu, perform a "checker deselect", do select just every
   other edges that have that direction
3. duplicate and seperate those edges to    a new object (Shift+D>Shift+P by selection) you now have a new object    with just those edges
4. you can choose to apply a wireframe modifier, or convert these Edges to curves and giving depth.

Comment: To make this answer more useful please add images that detail the workflow and the final result.