# How do I make a striped texture?

Tags: texturing, bezier-curves

Okay everyone, do you remember the game Five Nights at Freddy's:The Sister Location?

Well, I'm trying to make the stripe texture that was used for the springs that surround the endoskeletons and looks like a layer of muscle tissue.

Take Ennard as an example of what I'm talking about.

I'm using a stripe image texture for this and I can't unwrap it correctly on the bezier circle.

Here it is: [image]

Can you guy's please help me out?

And to be specific,the rendering engine I'm using is Cycles.
[image]

Comment: Please add what rendering engine you are using to the question.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66204/how-to-create-a-torus-with-divided-cuts-that-correspond-to-the-direction-of-the/66214#66214

Comment: I didn't know there was a duplicate of the question I asked until you showed me the link CGeaton